# How to deselect the child selection while unchecking the parent selection in InfoPath multi select cascading dropdown list

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath, infopath-rules, infopath-data-connections, infopath-form

I have a multi-select cascading dropdown list in my InfoPath form - it displays city based on the state selection inside the repeating table - this works fine. The problem is, once the user selects the city and again deselects the state - it should uncheck or deselect the particular city as well. For example, I have selected all states from left like **Karnataka, MA, TN** which displays all mapping cities in the right side like **Bangalore, Chennai, Mumbai**. Now, if I uncheck the state "**TN**" from the left side, it should automatically uncheck the city "**Chennai**" which is not happening.

[image: How to deselect the child selection while unchecking the parent selection in InfoPath multi-select cascading dropdown list]

So far what I have done is - applied a rule on **Sate** selection control "**This field changes**" and action selected as **set field value** to "**City**" as empty but this does not resolve this issue. Any guidance and help are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce this issue. The only workaround without code currently I find is that users should firstly uncheck the child selection, then uncheck the parent selection.

Or, you can try to use code to achieve it.